# Query for facts from list

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and i want to solve this problem. Suppose I have a list say
`List` i.e.    `[a,b,c]`
now i have some facts say
`likes(a,banana).

likes(b,orange).

likes(c,apple).

likes(d,grapes).`

---

So if I make a query

`?- my_functor(List,X).

X=[banana,orange,apple].`

---

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
?- List=[a,b,c], findall(X, (member(Y, List), likes(Y, X)), Xs).
List = [a, b, c],
Xs = [banana, orange, apple].
```

Explanation:

[`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) is called an 'all-solutions' predicate which seeks to find all possible values unifiable to the first argument (here, that's the variable `X`) to solutions for the seconds argument (here, that's the conjunction `(member(Y, List), likes(Y, X))`), and places all values for `X` into a list, bound to the third argument (here, that's `Xs`).

Notice that the inner expression generating the values for `X` is a statement that *backtracks* to provide different assignments for `X`:

```
?- member(Y, [a,b,c]), likes(Y, X).
Y = a,
X = banana ;
Y = b,
X = orange ;
Y = c,
X = apple ;
false.
```

Tested with SWI-Prolog.

Note that [`findall/3` also appears in GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc103) amongst most other implementations.